# -Timeout to elect master- from only one member of a functional Neo4j HA cluster

Tags: java, neo4j, high-availability

I got a neo4j HA setup here with two instances in two differente machines + one embedded running in yet another machine.

Neo4j version is 2.0.0-M03.

Here are my neo4j.properties:

First instance: **192.168.1.187**

```
keep_logical_logs=50M size
online_backup_enabled=true
ha.server_id=1
ha.server=192.168.1.187:6001
online_backup_server=192.168.1.187:6051
ha.cluster_server=192.168.1.187:5001
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.187:5001,192.168.1.222:5002
ha.pull_interval=2s
```

Second instance: **192.168.1.222**

```
keep_logical_logs=50M size
online_backup_enabled=true
ha.server_id=2
ha.server=192.168.1.222:6002
online_backup_server=192.168.1.222:6052
ha.cluster_server=192.168.1.222:5002
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.187:5001,192.168.1.222:5002
ha.pull_interval=2s
```

and in the embedded one (**192.168.1.130**) I use these properties

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
ha.server_id=3
ha.initial_hosts=192.168.1.187:5001,192.168.1.222:5002
ha.server=192.168.1.130:6003
ha.cluster_server=192.168.1.130:5003
ha.pull_interval=2s
```

Now, I do a `./neo4j start` at **192.168.1.187** and **192.168.1.222** and everything works. The cluster is up.

From there, when I start my java project, the embedded neo4j gets in the cluster. When I stop it, it gets out. No problem. If I change anything from the embedded database, the changes are reflected on every member. If I open **192.168.1.222**'s webadmin and change something from there, it's also reflected on my embedded database.

BUT, if I do anything on **192.168.1.187**'s webadmin, it gives me a timeout error.

```
TransactionFailureException

Timeout waiting for cluster to elect master

StackTrace:
org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.beginTx(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:207)
org.neo4j.kernel.TransactionBuilderImpl.begin(TransactionBuilderImpl.java:39)
org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:882)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:102)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:70)
org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:85)
org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:80)
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:95)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
```

**192.168.1.222**'s webadmin is still perfectly fine, and the embedded database too. I can still make changes to one and see it reflected in the other, but I can't do anything from **192.168.1.187**.

Is that supposed to happen? Am I missing something? ):

**Update:**

I found some problems with the addresses. "postgresdb" will map to **192.168.1.222** AT **222** but to **192.168.1.22** at **187**. And I didn't use the hostname anywhere, but somehow it went with the hostname and that was causing a problem with **187** trying to connect to **192.168.1.22**.

To correct that, I added

```
192.168.1.187        neodb1
192.168.1.222        neodb2
```

to `192.168.1.187/etc/hosts` and `192.168.1.222/etc/hosts` and changed all the properties to point to **neodb1** and **neodb2** instead of **192.168.1.187** and **192.168.1.222**.

BUT, that didn't solve the initial problem, I'm afraid.

The "messages.log"s are big, so I put them on pastebin (and hastebin since pastebin complained about heavy load when I was pasting the third one), but here they are:

> http://pastebin.com/ti4iYZ1V - 187
>
> http://pastebin.com/H9JcUybG - 222
>
> http://hastebin.com/mefeveqebi.sm - embedded

I should probably also mention that **192.168.1.130** was just a test machine and the real embedded database (which now is in use) also runs at **192.168.1.187**. Though I don't think that will make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to attach the log file which you can find at 'data/graph.db/messages.log' for each of the neo4j instances?

I've seen that error happen if a machine incorrectly announces its hostname/IP address when it joins the cluster but your configuration at first glance looks ok to me so it'd be interesting to see what's actually going on.

Mark

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to those PC's on this weekend, but this monday I'll update my answer with the logs.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Updated the answer with some new things and the logs. (Oh, and also, lol, "this monday I'll update my question**", not answer. Damn brains with bugs.)

Comment: Hey

I couldn't see the original error message that you mentioned in any of the messages.log that you provided unless I totally missed it. 

Could you go to the web admin at this url:

http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/info/org.neo4j/High%20Availability/

Change the hostname of course and paste in the contents of that page?

Mark

Comment: Hey, I'm sure I tried a random cypher query just to make sure the exception would be at the logs. Are you sure that kind of problem should appear in the messages.log? D: Also, the one with problems is the one at **187**. It returned this when I went to that page on webadmin http://hastebin.com/pamoyuwira.hs  Should I do that for the other standalone instance as well?

Comment: Hey,

Sorry I didn't get any notifications on this and now your two hastebin  links have expired.

Could you ping me on twitter @markhneedham or email m.h.needham at the gmail and attach all the logs and I'll look at it further.

Sorry for the delay, Mark